# Disable reify in npm

Tags: npm

How do I disable this in npm 7? It is bringing my npm installs to a crawl. It's terrible. I'm about to revert to npm 6.

Always shows things like `reify:popper.js: etc etc` when installing

Comment: Having the same issue right now. It's unbearable on NPM v7.